# Regex match an optional ending and prefer to do so

Tags: c#, regex

I' failry new to regex, and wish to match these two lines:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
    "#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)\r\n"
```

So far I have this:

```
(\\s+)?(\")?(#)(if\\s+!defined\\(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL\\)\\s+\\|\\|\\s+defined\\()(\\w+)(\\))
```

However, the last part is giving me trouble:

```
\r\n"
```

I can match this and make it optional, no problem, with this:

```
(\\r\\n")
```

However, I wish to capture it in a group if it is there (I think greedy is what I need)
So far, all my attempts have resulted in it not being matched if it is there because it is optional.

Can I force the regex engine to continue searching even if it is there, so I can get a capture group for it?

Comment: First, you capture a lot of things you apparently don't need, like `(#)`. Consider using non-capturing group: `(?:#)`. Or leaving ungrouped, really, like `\\s*` instead of `(\\s+)?` - do you really need to capture these spaces? Second, you are using `"...\\r\\n"` syntax for your pattern. Consider using `@"...\r\n"` syntax. These together will make your life easier. Regarding the question... did you mean `@"...(?:\r\n)?"")"`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do actually need these groups because I need to put the string back together in the exact order as it was, except one group that is replaced with something else.

Comment: Replaced? Then why not `Regex.Replace(input, pattern, evaluator)`? .NET regexes have lookbehind, lookahead and stuff...

Comment: Eugene, unfortunately the same thing happens. It matches the line, but the capture group for "(\r\n)?" is empty (because it matched without the optional part I suppose. But I need that part so I can render it back into the output :(

Comment: Ok, here is what I want: Take the AFX_TARG_ENU, create a hash, replace that occurrence with the hash. Everything else in the line should be the same. But I don't know if it's called AFX_TARG_ENU or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=#if\s+!\s*defined\s*\(\s*AFX_RESOURCE_DLL\s*\)\s*\|\|\s*defined\s*\(\s*)\w+(?=\s*\))";
string result = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, match => Hash(match.Value));
```

Which gives an output like this:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(QUZYX1RBUkdfRU5V)
   "#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(QUZYX1RBUkdfRU5V)\r\n"
```

The regex is a bit ugly, but that's because I allow for more spaces. Generally it consists of:

```
(?<=...) #A positive lookbehind with text that must appear before the match
\w+      #Text to replace
(?=...)  #A positive lookahead with text that must appear after the match
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and apologies for the late reply. I tried what you suggested and it actually does what I want, so I voted yours as answer. Also, the idea of positive lookahead and lookbehind will be very valuable for me in the future! Thanks again!